# Draw relative to right end of node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I'm new to `tikz` and I guess this is a very easy problem. Still I couldn't find the solution.

I want to use `tikz` to draw a background for my headlines. Therefore I created the following command:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\headline}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[gray] (0,2mm) -- (5mm-2mm,2mm) -- (5mm,0) -- (2mm,0) -- (0,2mm);
        \node (A) at (12mm,1mm) {\Large\textsc{#1}};
        \fill[gray] (A.east|-0,2mm) -- (\textwidth-2mm,2mm) -- (\textwidth,0) -- (A.east|-0,0) -- (A.east|-0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
    \headline{test}
\end{document}
```

The result is the following:
[image: Result of \headline command]

But I want the left bottom corner of the second line behind the text also to be cut off. Like in this image:

[image: Hoped result]

I tried to somehow add the missing 2mm but I didn't find a solution. I tried `([xshift=2mm]A.east|-0,2mm)`, `(A.east|-0+2mm,2mm)`, `\fill[gray] let \p{A}=(A) in (A.east|-0,2mm) -- (\textwidth-2mm,2mm) -- (\textwidth,0) -- (\x{A}+2mm,0) -- (A.east|-0,0);` and many other things I came across when searching. But I didn't get it to work.

---

How do I add the missing 2mm relative to the end of the node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the tikz-library `calc` to calculate the missing coordinate as `($(A.east|-0,0)+(2mm,0)$)`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\headline}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[gray] (0,2mm) -- (5mm-2mm,2mm) -- (5mm,0) -- (2mm,0) -- cycle;
        \node (A) at (12mm,1mm) {\Large\textsc{#1}};
        \fill[gray] (A.east|-0,2mm) -- (\textwidth-2mm,2mm) -- (\textwidth,0) -- ($(A.east|-0,0)+(2mm,0)$) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \headline{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. Also thank you for `cycle`. Just one more question: Why/When do I need the `$` signs?

Comment: @miile7 The `$` signs indicate that the `calc` library is to be used for coordinate calculations (in our case, addition). For details, see section [13.5 Coordinate Calculations of the tikz manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).